# on checkbox click some php code to be executed in the same page

Tags: php, database, jquery

I have form inside the `while` condition in `echo` because in while condition, some value comes from the database and according to each row, user perform an action in the form.

In the form, the checkbox is `onclick` of the checkbox, i want the `PHP` code to be executed in the same page which will update the database.

```
echo "<tr><td>Assign employee ID</td><td>Task Assign</td><td>Date of Assigning Task</td>
                <td>Given Task time</td><td>Time of given task</td><td colspan=3>Read message</td></tr></tr>";

                $message=mysql_query("select * from message where receiver_id='$myid' and is_read != 1 ");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($message))
                {
                $sender_id=$row["sender_id"];
                $receiver_id=$row["receiver_id"];
                $task_assign=$row["message"];
                $date=$row["date"];
                $time_of_given_task=$row["time"];

                echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$sender_id."</td><td>".$receiver_id."</td><td>".$task_assign."</td>
                    <td>".$date."</td><td>".$time_of_given_task."</td><td>
                        <form action='message_to_read.php?date=$date&time=$time_of_given_task&receive=$receiver_id' method=post>
                        <input type=checkbox value=checked name=check onclick=foo();></td>
                        </form>
                        </td>
                        </tr>";

                }

                echo "</table>";
                function foo()
                {
                $todaydate=$_REQUEST["date"];

                echo $todaydate;
                $time_of_given_task=$_REQUEST["time"];
                echo $time_of_given_task;
                $empid=$_REQUEST["receive"];
                echo $empid;
                    $test2=mysql_query("update message set is_read='$update' where receiver_id='$empid' and date='$todaydate' and time='$time_of_given_task' ");
                }
```

Comment: Your `onclick=foo()` is not going to call the PHP `foo` function... do you have a javascript foo() function? Your checkbox is also not setting a value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an AJAX problem to me. If you are using JQuery simply use AJAX built in functionality.

```
$(document).on('change', '#YOUR_CHECKBOX', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //if checkbox is checked do ajax call
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT,
       data: { OPTIONAL : DATA },
       success: function(result) { }
    });
  }
});
```

**change** event would be better than **click** event in this situation

Comment: This. Once the page loads on the client you can not run php on that page. You need to: call the server(php code), run the code, return response to client via some transport medium (socket/XHR/etc), and finally update page with the new data.

Comment: what are you talking about you can simply use AJAX to call PHP scripts without page reload. Please read about AJAX.

Comment: That's basically what I'm saying, just in step-by-step form. Sorry for the confusion.